# Convert int array to string in C#

Tags: c#

I have an `int[]`:

```
RXBuffer[0], RXBuffer[1],..., RXBuffer[9]
```

where each value represents an ASCII code, so 0x31 represents `1`, 0x41 represents `A`.

How do I convert this to a 10 character string ?

So far I've tried `Data = RxBuffer.ToString();`. But it shows `Data` equals to `System.Int32[]` which is not what my data is.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are all of these integers single-digit 0-9?

Comment: not really. Alphabet also got.

Comment: then I'm confused; if this is an "int array", what does each integer represent? What is an "alphabet" in in "int array"? Are these unicode code points? or....? Frankly, I think everyone here is assuming that `{0,1,2,3}` would become `"0123"`

Comment: Perhaps sample input/output would be a great idea

Comment: The int array is ascii value. like 0x31 for 1 or 0x41 for A.

Comment: @manian84 k, you **really** should have made that clear. And frankly, `char[]` would be a better choice. I'll update my answer.

Comment: ASCII codes are `byte`s, not `int`s. You should make that a `byte[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the "int array" is values in the 0-9 range (which is the only way that makes sense to convert an "int array" length 10 to a 10-character string) - a bit of an exotic way:

```
string s = new string(Array.ConvertAll(RXBuffer, x => (char)('0' + x)));
```

But pretty efficient (the `char[]` is right-sized automatically, and the string conversion is done just with math, instead of `ToString()`).

---

Edit: with the revision that makes it clear that these are actually ASCII codes, it becomes simpler:

```
string s = new string(Array.ConvertAll(RXBuffer, x => (char)x));
```

Although frankly, if the values are ASCII (or even unicode) it would be better to store it as a `char[]`; this covers the same range, takes half the space, and is just:

```
string s = new string(RXBuffer);
```

Comment: U mean this? string s = new string(Array.ConvertAll(RXBuffer, x => (char)x));
Or this? string s = new string(RXBuffer);

Comment: Yours is simpler and more clever. I like it.

Answer (score 3):

LolCoder
All you need is :

```
string.Join("",RXBuffer);
```

============== Or =================

```
        int[] RXBuffer = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        string result  =  string.Join(",",RXBuffer);
```

Comment: But I don't want it to have comma in between.

Comment: The int array is ascii value. like 0x31 for 1 or 0x41 for A

Comment: You won't get commas.. it will generate "0123456789"